# Related to XSLT mapping

Tags: xslt-1.0

Source XML :

```
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><SoapResponse 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><Response/><TicketId/><LogId/><Error xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OpenSystems.Web.OCKSoap.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:code>1233</a:code><a:message>No se pudo obtener una conexión de base de datos</a:message></Error></SoapResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Expected Target XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:MT_SAP_GoodsIssue_Res xmlns:ns0="http://www.aes.com/SapToOsf/GoodsIssue">
<SoapResponse>
  <Response/>
  <TicketId/>
  <LogId/>
  <Error>
     <code/>
     <message/>
  </Error>
</SoapResponse>
</ns0:MT_SAP_GoodsIssue_Res>
```

I have tried with below XSLT but it didn't give proper result.

```
    <xsl:template match="*">

            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

            </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>
```

XSLT O/P :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Envelope><Body><SoapResponse><Response/><TicketId/><LogId/><Error><code>1233</code><message>No se pudo obtener una conexi��n de base de datos</message></Error></SoapResponse></Body></Envelope>
```

Please help me to get expected output via XSLT.